# Hibernate: 1st level cache

Tags: hibernate, session

Could someone tell me how could I peek into objects being managed by a session in Hibernate?

I am trying to use eclipse debugger and drill into **persistenceContext** but I am not sure if that is where I would find the objects being managed by hibernate session.

Could someone tell me how to find out the objects that are being managed by Hibernate objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to use this information simply for your own benefit and learning?  You won't be able to access the information as far as I know in any sort of standard JPA-approved method.

However, if you're using Hibernate, you could put a breakpoint and dig into Hibernate's implementation of PersistenceContext.java which is called StatefulPersistenceContext.java.  There should be a map of entities and collections loaded.  You will of course need the Hibernate source code for this.

The fields should be named something like...

```
private Map entitiesByKey;
private Map proxiesByKey;
private Map collectionsByKey;
```

EDIT: Don't forget to toggle "Show Logical Structures" in the Eclipse debugger or navigating those maps will drive you insane.

Comment: Yes, I was just curious to see the managed objects by hibernate session. I had set the breakpoint and was looking for the changes in the debugger under **persistenceContext** when I was persisting a transient object but wasn't seeing any. I wonder what was I missing when i was trying it. This was exactly what I needed. Many many thanks :)